# How's the CMD trip bonuses from extra legs work?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, summoner, eidolon, trip

I'm playing a summoner in a new campaign with some friends, using the half-elf wild caller archetype so gaining evolution points with an extra 1/2 every level. Well a friend told me that for every set of legs after two you get a bonus to your trip CMD. Is this true? How's this work, and is there a cap to this? Or, on the flip side, at what point can you physically not be tripped?

Comment: Where are you getting the information "that seems true"? Does your friend have a source for this information?

Comment: No source but multiple creatures with four legs get a +4 to trip cmd due to more legs to trip.

Comment: I'm editing this question to also ask people to verify what your friend told you before expounding on it. While it may seem [very truthy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truthiness), that doesn't mean it's *actually true.* If such a bonus doesn't exist, expounding on it will be difficult. This gives you the opportunity to get a confirmation, a reference, an explanation, *and* answers to your original questions, if such a thing exists.

Comment: While thats true it doesn't state a serpentine base form can't be tripped while tripping a snake in my opinion wouldn't be possible.

Comment: Also, without further ado - welcome to the site. I see from your informed badge you've already read our [tour]; thanks for doing that. I hope you enjoy your stay here! When you reach 20 rep, you'll also be able to talk in our [chat].

Comment: Thank you for the welcome, I've been lurking on this site for a while getting information. It's been very helpful. Hopefully I'll be able to spread some of my knowledge back to the community

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's partly true:

> If your attack exceeds the target's CMD, the target is knocked prone. If your attack fails by 10 or more, you are knocked prone instead. If the target has more than two legs, add +2 to the DC of the combat maneuver attack roll for each additional leg it has. Some creatures—such as oozes, creatures without legs, and flying creatures—cannot be tripped.

<sup>([d20PFSRD: Combat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Trip))</sup>

+2 for every leg, not every pair of legs. There's no cap, and no point at which extra legs guarantee immunity to tripping.

Really, I don't see the point of one; a creature with a hundred legs, having a +196 bonus to their CMD, need not fear any tripper except one abusing the rules for unboundedly high trip checks.

Answer (score 4):

## Your friend is almost right

The combat maneuver [Trip](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Trip) says, "If the target has more than two legs, add +2 to the DC of the combat maneuver attack roll for each additional leg it has." This should include your multilegged eidolon. There's no cap to the DC increase, but the point of diminishing returns *is* reached rapidly.

Also, in case you're wondering, [Carrying Capacity](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/alignment-description/carrying-capacity) says, "Quadrupeds can carry heavier loads than bipeds can," and then explains how to calculate that encumbrance; presumably, a creature that has more legs than a quadruped benefits likewise.

Answer (score 1):

The rules for an Eidolon's evolutions are listed in the Eidolon section. 
The evolution *Limbs* has the following to say about legs:

> An eidolon grows an additional pair of limbs. These limbs can take one of two forms. They can be made into legs, complete with feet. Each pair of legs increases the eidolon’s base speed by 10 feet.

The combat page says about *Trip* attacks:

> If the target has more than two legs, add +2 to the DC of the combat maneuver attack roll for each additional leg it has. Some creatures—such as oozes, creatures without legs, and flying creatures—cannot be tripped.

So, it seems like there is no hard cap, although it will quickly become impractical to simply continue adding more and more limbs to your Eidolon.